# Show HTML Content only if URL parameter is present

Tags: javascript

On the site I'm working on, we want to display some content on the 1st page of the collections/categories (which can be up to 7 pages long) only. I've tried writing some javascript to have it only show on the base URL which has no parameters or the first page only, but it's not working for me. It is still showing on every page. Does anybody have any idea as to what I may be missing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if((location.search.indexOf('page=')<0)||(location.search.indexOf('page=1')>=0)){
$('div.collection-main').find('div.coll-more-info').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:-** changed the condition to,

`if((location.search.indexOf('page=') === -1)||
    (location.search.indexOf('page=1') !== -1))`

The condition looks ok, except a syntax error,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if((location.search.indexOf('page=') === -1)||(location.search.indexOf('page=1') !== -1)){
    $('div.collection-main').find('div.coll-more-info').css('display','block');
    }
});
```

Added `}` to close the if loop.

Comment: Still shows on "page=2" as well...any ideas? But thank you for catching that. I've been looking at it so long I feel cross-eyed! :)

Comment: can you give the url where it is showing up but it should not.. like the page 2 as you have said

Comment: try adding `$('div.collection-main').find('div.coll-more-info').css('display','none');` before the if loop.. hope that element is set to `display: none` while the page is loading as the condition seems fine

Comment: @Andrea I've updated my answer with a few changes, like checking if `index === -1`. Can you share the Url for page 2 and check my previous comment (the above one `^`) ?

Comment: your suggestion of adding that line in before the if loop worked. Thanks so much!!